# An issue when I use unidirectional One-To-Many and Table Per Class InheritanceType in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, class-hierarchy, joined-subclass, table-per-class

I have a class `Person` and a class hierarchy which has three classes, when I use InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS for the class hierarchy, it got the "Batch update" problem. Please see the below code. `AbstractBase` is the base class for the class hierarchy.

```
public class Person {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
  private String id; 

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name="Employee_employees_Person", referencedColumnName = "id")
  @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.PERSIST, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE})
  private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
 }

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@javax.persistence.Access(javax.persistence.AccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class AbstractBase {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String id;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}    
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "EmployeeClass")
@javax.persistence.Access(javax.persistence.AccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee extends AbstractBase implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    @Column(name="Employee_employees_Person")
    private String Employee_employees_Person_ID;
}

@Entity
public class Manager extends Employee {
   @Property(name="ManagerLevel")
   @Column(name="ManagerLevel")
   private String level;

   public String getLevel() {
      return level;
   }

   public void setLevel(String level) {
    this.level = level;
   }
}
```

Test code:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
Person a = new Person();
Employee e1 = new Employee();
e1.setName("Bill");

Manager m1 = new Manager();
m1.setName("Amanda");
m1.setLevel("VP");
a.getEmployees().add(e1);
a.getEmployees().add(m1);
em.persist(a);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Output:

`org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1"`

I found that Hibernate doesn't update the `Manager` table when I went through the hibernate sql. When I changed the InheritanceType to `InheritanceType.JOINED`, the code works well. Do I miss something in the unidirectional One-To-Many configuration?

----------------------------------update--------------------------------

In 'Person' class, I changed @JoinColumn to @JoinTable in One-To-Many annotation,  the testing code works well. Is there any missed configuration for @JoinColumn configuration when its target class is annotated by "InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS"?

See below detailed annotation:

```
@OneToMany
//@JoinColumn(name="Employee_employees_Person", referencedColumnName = "id")
@JoinTable (
        name = "Person_employees_Employee",
        joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="Person_ID", referencedColumnName="id") },
        inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="Employee_ID", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
)
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.PERSIST, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE})
private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
```

-------------------------------------update--------------------------------

I tried the code with Hibernate 5.2.5 Final, the issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's related to [HHH-9864](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9864). Try with Hibernate 5.2.5 and see if it works better.

Comment: Vlad, thanks your information. I tried with Hibernate 5.2.5 final, but the issue still exists